# GNU ddrescue imaging of failing hard drive is extremely slow

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-recovery

My friend has a (nearly full) failing 1 TB Western Digital My Passport. It will only occasionally mount on my MacBook, and refuses outright to mount on my Ubuntu box. I'm trying to use GNU ddrescue 1.19 (on the Ubuntu box) to create an image of the drive onto a 2 TB Western Digital My Passport Ultra. The failing drive is NTFS and the destination drive is formatted to ExFat.

Both are connected via USB 3. Even using `-n` to skip scraping, I'm averaging a read speed of ~60-70 kB/s. This works out to about half a year to make its way through the full terabyte. Whenever ddrescue starts, generally the first 2 or 3 reads report ~1-2 MB/s or more, but then it immediately, inevitably plummets.

I've looked around the internet and found lots of people with similar issues, but no good solutions. I've tried playing around with the `-b` sector size, the `-c` cluster size, and the `-d` kernel cache bypass, but no luck. My `infile` is `/dev/sdc` and my `outfile` is a .dd file on the output disk, which is mounted in /media.

What else can I try to speed this thing up?

**Edit:**

SMART output:

```
$ sudo smartctl -H /dev/sdc
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-41-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART STATUS RETURN: incomplete response, ATA output registers missing
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
Failed Attributes:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   133   133   140    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 2829
```

Comment: In what way is the drive failing- do you have the SMART errors that are/were reported? Have you tried `ddrescue` on a similar, non-failing drive? Anecdotally, I have also used `ddrescue` on a very knackered drive and yes it can take half a year to fully read if there are severe problems when reading.

Comment: @bertieb added SMART output for drive

Comment: Thanks. When I encountered an incredibly slow ddrescue (one that makes 60-70 kB/s look great), the drive in question was taking a long time to retry reads, possibly as a result of something in the controller firmware. This is all speculation and hearsay though, so if someone can answer in a way that speeds it up I'll be most interested to read!

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, but what strikes me as odd is that the beginning of the disk behaves just fine (getting around 50MB/s throughput) but then after about 150GB out of 500 it starts to tank (won't go above 121 kB/s). I thought maybe I could "skip past it" by setting `--min-read-rate=256000` but this didn't skip ahead very quickly. Even trying `--input-position=490000000000` to jump to copying the last 10GB didn't affect the speed. I've also tried this another computer with a USB<->SATA adapter and got roughly the same results.

Answer (score 7):

Step 1) Make sure the drive can be seen on the bus:

> sudo lshw -businfo

Step 2) Get yourself hddsupertool [here.](http://www.sdcomputingservice.com/hddsupertool/download)

Run as root, select the device, and select the VSC entry.

Step 3) Select this entry:

> 4) WD royl (Marvel) patch mod 02 (slow fix)

Step 4) You want to first

> 1) Read the module to a file and create the patch.

followed by

> 2) Write the patched data back to the disk.

Step 5) Go back to VSC entry, select:

> 5) WD royl (Marvel) patch mod 32 (slow fix)

and perform entries 1 & 2 again (reading mod, patching, and writing back)

Note: It may tell you it's failed on the final step. It still worked for me.

Step 6) Power cycle the drive

What you've just done: You've cleared the SMART status, and the file relocation list. The re-lo list contains info about which sectors need to be relocated, which in WD's case happens quite often on a failed read.

Credit: 
[**Spildit**](http://www.hddoracle.com/viewtopic.php?f=86&t=848) (Manual Method of doing this) & **Scott Dwyer** (Author of hddsupertool)

I went from 130KB/s scan i/o speed in testdisk to 11-13MB/s after the fix, and I was able to recover data at +100MB/s from as far back as the very first time I used the drive. This was after a week of researching a ton of dead ends.

Good Luck!

Comment: Why are people downvoting with no explanation? I had this exact same issue, and after hours of digging, the procedure I posted here was the -only- solution to the problem. Can whoever downvoted at least **explain** why they've done so? How else am I supposed to learn? I'm here to *help.*

Comment: As per @bertieb, he was absolutely correct. The relocation table stored in firmware is the culprit on these drives...

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, it speed up dumping process a lot. Most of the reads went up from ~30kB/s to tens of MB/s. Only difference is that I used https://github.com/ISpillMyDrink/OpenSuperClone instead, seems like HDDSuperClone is abandoned now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Warning / Disclaimer

This procedure is considered risky. If your data is valuable enough, you should go straight to a Data Recovery professional, as any try on your part might make their work harder, and thus even more expansive, if possible at all.

That said, it worked flawlessly for me, but YMMV.

This does not mean your drive will be usable again, only that you can recover what remains readable at a reasonable speed.

### WD Slow issue fix

1. get [HDDSuperClone](http://www.hddsuperclone.com/sitev1/) from its [downloads area](http://www.hddsuperclone.com/downloadsv1/public/812f01), with a recent debian, you should choose `hddsuperclone_xxxx_amd64.deb`
2. install with `sudo apt install ./hddsuperclone_*_amd64.deb` from your Downloads directory
3. You can install dependencies with the supplied `hddsuperclone-install-depends-deb.sh` script, but only `apt-get install libusb-0.1 -y` should be necessary for this procedure.
4. Run `sudo hddsuperclone --tool` in directory where root can write some files
5. `A) ATA Passthrough`
6. Choose your disk (triple check is some are similar)
7. `7) VSC`
8. `4) WD royl (Marvel) patch mod 02 (slow fix)`
9. `1) Read the module to a file and create the patch.`
10. `2) Write the patched data back to the disk.`
11. Type what you are asked for
12. `q) Quit`
13. Power cycle (unplug, replug) the disk
14. Perform again steps 4 to 7
15. but choose `5) WD royl (Marvel) patch mod 32 (slow fix additional)`
16. And again steps 9 to 13

Voilà, your disk now *thinks* that it has no bad blocks ! You know better of course. Back to ddrescue for me. The drive path changed at first power cycle, but came back after the second one.

### Credits

Full credits of course due to @SmokinGrunts, this a just an update of his answer.

Many thanks also to Scott Dwyer, the author of hddsupertool, which seems to be the only free tool to do this simple fix.

### Context

I've been trying to recover data from a WDC WD10JMVW-11AJGS2, usb-only disk, for a friend. This disk did make dreadful noises, so I ran a ddrescue as soon as I could. It started well, but after few minutes, it did slow to a crawl, nearly exactly 64KB/s...

I tried every possible ddrescue options, following advice where I could, to no avail. I blamed btrfs, which I've used for the first time as the target fs, and tried a of lot things that side also. Useless again.

Then I began to stumble on a lot a discussions of the dreaded "WD Slow issue", with mostly unhelpful or even rude comments. Then I arrived here, with the first real, free, solution.

I had to dig through the dense [HDDSuperClone documentation](http://www.hddsuperclone.com/sitev1/hddsuperclone/manual), to understand how to adapt the instructions here to the new version. Search for `wd_royl_patch_mod02` to get to the relevant part, nearly at the end. Thus I wanted to comment, but being new, I had to write an answer. I tried to do my best, please advice if it could be better.

Regards.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, it speed up dumping process a lot. Most of the reads went up from ~30kB/s to tens of MB/s. Only difference is that I used https://github.com/ISpillMyDrink/OpenSuperClone instead, seems like HDDSuperClone is abandoned now. Thanks!